# Type of the result using DeepFace.analyze()

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter, deepface

when I use DeepFace.analyze the type of the output variable is ''list'' instead of ''dict''.

I don't know where the problem is exactly, you can see my code below

```
import cv2  ## pip install opencv-python
from deepface import DeepFace  ## pip install deepface
img=cv2.imread('happyboy.jpg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
predictions = DeepFace.analyze(img)
type (predictions)
```

in this project I need the dominant emotion,so if I do

```
predictions['dominant_emotion']
```

I get error message

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

if someone can help me to have the predictions vector in dictionary format

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, I was having this issue as well. For some reason it was storing the dict in a list.

I don't know why the issue happened, but I solved it by storing the value in `list[0]`.

So in your case, it should be like:

```
pr = predictions[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue while I was trying to print 'dominant_emotion' without the other information. Maybe this will work for you:

```
print(predictions[0]['dominant_emotion'])

type(predictions[0]['dominant_emotion'])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 0):

deepface could focus on single face in images in the past. if you feed an image more than one face, then it was discarded by the library. in its new release, it started to support many faces. that is why, output interface modified from dict to list. now, each item in its response means a face in the fed image.